# Console errors when opening the Winter Bash dialog

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

When visit any user profile page, I get some console errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at Object.addHatToGravatar (hakovaim.js?v=6:311)
    at wb-kovah.js?v=3:810
    at Object.<anonymous> (wb-kovah.js?v=3:733)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at withCurrentHat (wb-kovah.js?v=3:731)
    at putHat (wb-kovah.js?v=3:807)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (wb-kovah.js?v=3:845)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

[image]

I also (randomly) get errors when I visit https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep#winter-bash:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats10607772 is not defined
    at current-hats?callback=winterBashCurrentHats10607772&userids=10607772&host=stackoverflow.com&_=1608121692061:1
```

[image]

where 10607772 is my Stack Overflow user id.

No userscripts are running. I am using Chrome version 87.0.4280.88 on Windows 10.

Comment: I can't repro. Can you change hats and change back and see if it still happens?

Comment: @YaakovEllis nope, still. I've also repro'd with a different account visiting quite a few profile pages.