# Why is the JavaScript file that deal with Winter Bash hats called "hakovaim.js"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hebrew

Looking through Network tab on Chrome developer tools, I noticed a file called "`hakovaim.js`" and in it seems to be code that controls the Winter Bash hats.

Why was this name chosen? The word "hakovaim" means "the hats" in Hebrew. I was wondering if this was created by a Hebrew speaking person, or is that just a coincidence?

And if it is the Hebrew word, then why would that be used on this file name instead of a more useful English word?

(Hopefully the person who actually created that file will see this question, but if anyone else knows, I am really curious about this.)

Comment: Yes, the person in charge of Winter Bash this year is a Hebrew speaker.

Comment: In sample output in *[Console errors when opening the Winter Bash dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358016)*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Winter Bash 2020 was largely created by [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/Yaakov-Ellis), who lives in Israel and does indeed speak Hebrew.

He probably included the name as a sort of Easter Egg.

ולמה שלא יעשה את זה?

Comment: חמוד מאוד. :). i just hope future ppl dont get confused. lol.

Comment: does anyone know of any other hebrew "easter eggs"?

Comment: [Here's a famous one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#PHP)